# Is it possible to implement a map method into another map method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that I map within a React component to render some stuff. Each item in the array has another array `payroll_run_items` inside. I would like to get the sum of `amount` of all items in that sub-array within my map method. Is this even possible within map (s.th. like creating a map inside a map)? I could only make it happen via looping and calculating the value beforehand outside the map method.

payrollRuns object:

```
(23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
amount: "0.00"
company: {id: 1, name: 'Example Ltd.', country: 'Germany', city: 'Munich', zip: '80801', …}
line_items: 0
month: {id: 55, period: '2024-03-01'}
payroll_run_items: Array(4)
0: {id: 338, amount: '3780.00', offer: {…}, month: {…}, payroll_run: {…}}
1: {id: 361, amount: '4428.28', offer: {…}, month: {…}, payroll_run: {…}}
2: {id: 384, amount: '3780.00', offer: {…}, month: {…}, payroll_run: {…}}
3: {id: 407, amount: '3780.00', offer: {…}, month: {…}, payroll_run: {…}}
```

```
const PayrollRuns = (props) => {

    const runItems = props.payrollRuns.map((run) =>
        <div key={run.id} className="flex p-4 text-lg">
          ..
          <div>{sum of all amounts of payroll_run_items array..}</div>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div className="runs-wrapper bg-white rounded-xl h-full w-48 shadow-sx-shadow p-4 flex flex-col">
            <h1 className="border-b-2 pb-4">Payroll Runs</h1>
            <div className="grow overflow-auto">{runItems}</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PayrollRuns
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do this... But what exactly you need to do, can you show the right JSON? The JSON seems to be truncated and it's moreover just a string?

Comment: `payroll_run_items` is an array of strings that appear to be JSON though... Could you specify how you want it to be summed?

Comment: The keyword _**"sum"**_ like any other form of item/value aggregation gives a strong hint towards utilizing [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use reduce:

```
const runItems = props.payrollRuns.map((run) =>
        <div key={run.id} className="flex p-4 text-lg">
          ..
          <div>{run.payroll_run_items.reduce((acc, value) => {
  return acc.amount + value.amount;
})}</div>
        </div>
    );
```